# How can I use custom slash commands within threads in Slack

Tags: javascript, slack, slack-api

I've setup a custom slash commands `/news` witihn slack and it works fine but I can't find a way to use trigger slash commands via threads.

I get the following error:  `/news is not supported in threads. Sorry!`

i've looked through the slack api documentation and i can't seem to find it. I know its possible because I have the `/giphy` app installed and I can use that in threads.

I found this article but it was not really helpful.
https://medium.com/slack-developer-blog/bringing-your-bot-into-threaded-messages-cd272a42924f

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: If this question is related to Javascript, you should probably add some code to not get deleted.

Comment: @Rojo thank you for the comment. Not sure what code to add since the issue is generic. I'll remove the javascript tag.

Comment: Well if you don't really have any code, then this isn't a coding question. Try finding answers on Slack Forums or super user.

Answer (score 19):

It's not possible to add app slash commands to a thread. Giphy is special cased in the codebase, which is why it works.

Comment: Appreciate the authoritative answer from someone on the Slack team.

Comment: Is this still the case, as of July 2023? Are slash apps still not usable in threads?

Comment: @costr it still seems to not be supported

Comment: Y tho?  This makes almost all the integrations/apps unusable.  Slack pushes hard for threaded messages but I cannot create a jira task or a zoom call after a long thread.

Comment: Why? This makes no sense to me. Is it a technical decision or some strategy or security concern? Will this be available in the future?